# Point with lat/long inside a circle

Tags: math

I know the formula for determining if a point(x, y) is inside a circle is `(x - x_c)^2 + (y - y_c)^2 < radius^2` but what if my x and y are in degrees (lat/long)?

Comment: how precise do you need it to be.  if you don't need it be super precise, you can always assume that the world is flat

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) for calculating distance from the center.

Comment: I actually need it to be precise. And I have already gone through that link -it's addressing a different topic.

Comment: That link is addressing the same topic exactly.

Comment: But I've already figured out how to calculate the radius. Edit: I see now. I have to basically calculate the distance between the point and the centre using the same logic and see if that's less than the radius. Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by interjay, the solution is to calculate the distance between the point and the center of the circle and compare it with the radius. The code is available here:

[Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)